# What if pandas.read_csv runs into an empty file in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dates.

```
dates = [20170203, 20170204 ...]
```

What I normally do is:

```
output = pd.concat([pd.read_csv('filename_{0}.csv'.format(x)) for x in dates])
```

However, when the file doesn't exist, the line doesn't work.

So I created a wrapper function:

```
output = pd.concat([reader('filename_{0}.csv'.format(x)) for x in dates])

def reader(x):
    if os.path.isfile(x):
        return pd.read_csv(x)
    else:
        ?????
```

Here comes the problem: if I don't know what the headers of the files are, what should I put as the return value?

Answer (score 2):

```
output = pd.concat([pd.read_csv('filename_{0}.csv'.format(x)) for x in dates if os.path.isfile('filename_{0}.csv'.format(x))])
```

Skips the invalid files from being passed to `pd.concat`.

Assuming the following files exist in the folder:

> file0.csv
>   file2.csv
>   file3.csv
>   file5.csv
>   file8.csv
>   file9.csv

```
dates = list(range(10))
results = ['file{0}.csv'.format(x) for x in dates if os.path.isfile('file{0}.csv'.format(x))]

# results:
#
# [file0.csv,
#  file2.csv,
#  file3.csv, 
#  file5.csv, 
#  file8.csv, 
#  file9.csv,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is called to return something for each possible file. Since you want to skip some, move the iteration logic into your function and turn it into a generator by [`yielding`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) names instead:

```
def reader(files_iterator):
    for filename in files_iterator:
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            yield pd.read_csv(x)
```

Use it like this:

```
output = pd.concat(list(reader('filename_{}.csv'.format(x) for x in dates)))
```